# Using a target size (torch.Size([28])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([28, 28, 10])) is deprecated. Error

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I have uploaded my code below in the link, i am not sure with the params and sizes. Thanks for the help [code here](https://github.com/swat08mx/code_stash/blob/d3962873732a9137485d26a4140d5f9fcbd6449b/Image_classifications.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

I found several errors - first of all you need flatten image, you need one hot coding for BCE loss or you should use Cross entropy Loss, and you need activation function for example Sigmoid, see the code below

```
mld = nn.Sequential(nn.Flatten(), nn.Linear(784,10), nn.Sigmoid())
loss_list=[]
epochs=100
loss_fn = nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(mld.parameters(), lr=0.1)
mld.train()
for epoch in range(epochs):
  for X_train, y_train in train_loader:
    pred = mld(X_train.float())
    print(pred.shape)
    print(torch.nn.functional.one_hot(y_train).shape)
    loss = loss_fn(pred, torch.nn.functional.one_hot(y_train, num_classes=10).float())
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    print(loss.item())
    loss_list.append(loss.item())
    optimizer.step()

mld.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    y_pred = mld(X_train)
accuracy = (y_pred.round() == y).float().mean()
print("Accuracy {:.2f}".format(accuracy * 100))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, i appreciate it. I am facing some troubles with this parameters and what to do and what not to, could you tell me how to proceed?

Comment: What is the problem, do you face? You should flatten your image before linear layer 784 is size of flatten image, and then use activation function to get predict for BCE read documentation how you should sent to it labels - they should be one-hot transformed